# The HTML source value of the WebBrowser Control does not change in C#

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser-control

In the Web browser control, the value was changed using innertext and is well verified.

```
HtmlElement htmlEleWebBrowser = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("id");
htmlEleWebBrowser.InnerText = "change";
```

using 'WindowForm'

This code above is in the 'WebBrowser_DocumentCompleted' event.

---

However.. if you check the internal html source code on the changed WebBrowser Control or extract it as an Excel file, the value does not change.

Why is that? please help me~

Comment: How do you execly check page code? Try use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_WebBrowser_DocumentText

Comment: Yes, I tried it, but it didn't change... and clicked "View Source" with a right mouse click in the Web browser control.

Comment: If you want to change the HTML source, you can try to read and modify it as a txt file. Or use [Html Agility Pack](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46717a5b-22cd-48c8-8c72-7a11c403e479/edit-html-document-using-c?forum=csharplanguage).